# Using custom functions in blockproc in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I wanted to use my own (custom) function in `blockproc` function. But I am not able to figure out how to actually incorporate this. I am new to MATLAB.

In this function I am trying to embed info (the bits of `LR_seq`) into the block. I am selecting a pair of pixels at a time in the block and trying to embed my info into it.

This is the code of my function:

```
function dataencode(block_struct,LR_seq)

LR_seq = vec2mat(LR_seq,2,4);%changing it into a 2,4 mat to make it fit into the for loop
LR_mat = zeros(4,4);%adding zero columns in between to convert it into 4,4 mat to fit into the for loop
LR_mat(:,1:2:end) = LR_seq;


for r = 1 : 4

for c = [1  3] 

x = uint16(block_struct.data(r,c)) ; 
y = uint16(block_struct.data(r,c+1));
x1 = de2bi(x,12); y1 = de2bi(y,12);
  if(~(2*x - y == 1) | ~(2*y - x == 1) | ~(2*x - y == 255) | ~(2*y - x == 255))
   if((x1(1) == 0) & (y1(1) == 0))  %because in maltab lsb comes first
     xt = (2*x - y) ; yt = (2*y - x);
       xt_bin = de2bi(xt,12); xt_bin(1) = 1; xtd = bi2de(xt_bin);block_struct.data(r,c) =xtd;
        yt_bin = de2bi(yt,12) ; yt_bin(1) = LR_mat(r,c); ytd = bi2de(yt_bin); block_struct.data(r,c+1) = ytd;
        elseif((x1(1) == 1) | (y1(1) == 1))
          x1(1) = 0 ; xtd = bi2de(x1) ; block.data(r,c) = xtd;
           y1(1) = LR_mat(r,c); ytd = bi2de(y1) ; block_struct.data(r,c+1) = ytd;
          end
         else
    x1(1) = 0; xtd = bi2de(x1) ; block.data(r,c) = xtd;
      ytd = bi2de(y1); block_struct.data(r,c+1) = ytd;
     end
   end
 end
end
```

`M` is a RGB 256x256 image in which I want to embed the sequence of bits `LR_seq`.

I am trying to call this function in the command window but it is giving me a empty matrix, please help out. This is my code for calling the function

```
 for ii = 1 : 8 : size(LR_seq)
     myfunc = @(block_struct) dataencode(block_struct,LR_seq(ii : ii+7));
     U_im_new = blockproc(M,[4 4],myfunc)
 end
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on line 10 of `dataencode` and when the code pauses there, checking what the current value of `block_struct` in the dataencode function's workspace is?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataencode` should take a `block_struct` in parameter. But your function `myfunc_red` calls the encode function with the data of the `block_struct`.

You may prefer to do this:

```
myfunc = @(block_struct) dataencode(block_struct,LR_seq(1 : 8));
U_im_r = blockproc(M(:,:,1),[4 4],myfunc);
```